# getDownloadUrl deprecated, so How do i get access to the URL of the image i uploaded onto the Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[CLICK TO SEE THE ACTIVITY WHERE THE DOWNLOAD URL OF THE IMAGE UPLOADED TO THE FIREBASE STORAGE IS REQUIRED.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVFt7.png)
I Want to get the Download URL of the uploaded image. getDownlaodUrl() is not working as it has been deprecated lately.So I want the alternate of that, so that I can use that url to display the image which i uploaded on the firebase storage  in another activity using Picasso.
So kindly tell me how to Retrieve the download URL of the images on the Firebase Storage.

Comment: is this a typo while posting question or you are using as it is `getDownlaodUrl() `?, because function is there in documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference

Comment: It is not  a typo. I used mStorage.getDownloadUrl().toString(); This gave an error , Required : String ; Found : Task<uri>

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDownloadUri()` as below it has changed in recent version, check documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

```
getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        System.out.println(uri.toString());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **mStorage** object name just use this

`downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();`

Comment: This doesn't work. Already tried.